# Moving a rectangle a certain offset in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two rectangles around the eyes. Now I want to draw three more rectangles, on the left side of the head, one on the upper side and the last on the right side. All these based on the position of the eyes. I've tried to shift the eye's rectangle by using Rect= Rect +- Point, but what I get is a bigger (or smaller) rectangle at the same location.

Any idea about how could I make this? Thanks in advance.
 Here my code:

```
for ( i = 0; i < eyes.size(); i++) {
    Rect eye_i = eyes[i];
    rectangle(frame, eye_i, CV_RGB(255, 0, 255), 1);
    DrawRectangle(eye_i, frame);
    Mat eyeroi = frame(eyes[i]);
    imwrite("eye.jpeg", eyeroi);
}

void DrawRectangle(Rect rect,Mat frame) {
    Rect up = rect + Point(-8,10);
    Rect right = rect + Point(20, 0);
    Rect left = rect + Point(-8, 0);
    rectangle(frame, up, CV_RGB(0, 255, 255), 1);
    rectangle(frame, right, CV_RGB(0, 255, 255), 1);
    rectangle(frame, left, CV_RGB(0, 255, 255), 1);
```

}

Comment: That should be correct. Please double check

Comment: Yes, you are right, the only problem was about the coordinates of the points... Thank you !